# Отправка значения влажности в Telegram

Tags: c++, telegram, arduino

Подскажите пож-та, как можно через FastBot отправить в Telegram данные с датчика влажности HTU21D GY-21? для получения влажности использую библиотеку GyverHTU21D, посоветуйте, как будет лучше?

Код (не работает, как надо):

```
void newMsg(FB_msg& msg) { 
  if (htu.readTick()){
    bot.sendMessage(String(htu.getHumidity()));
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаете переменную хранящую данные с датчика. После Stringa в скобках пишете название переменной и все должно заработать. В моем случае вот так:

bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, String(temp), "");

В чем выражается неправильная работа кода?